# Exact versus numerical approximation of an integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Why does the following approximation work very well for small `theta`'s but not for large `theta`'s?

---

$$
I = \int_0^\infty x (1 + \theta x)^{-2 \left(\frac{1}{\theta} + 1 \right)} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

**Exact evaluation using integration by part**

$$
I = \frac{1}{2(\theta + 2)}
$$

**Approximation using Gauss-Laguerre quadrature**
$$
I \approx \sum_{k=1}^N w_k \exp(x_k) \, x_k (1 + \theta x_k)^{-2 \left(\frac{1}{\theta} + 1 \right)}
$$
where the $x_k$'s and the $w_k$'s can be found, e.g., [here](http://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1281279441X).

**Comparison (N = 100)**

- `theta = 0.5806`:

  `true = 0.1937534`  and  `approx = 0.1937522`
- `theta = 15`:

  `true = 0.02941176`  and `approx = 0.01662866`

---

**my R-code**

```
#------ package ------
library(gaussquad)
#---------------------

#------ f(x) ------
f <- function(x, theta)
{
  x * (1 + theta * x)^(-2 * ((1 / theta) + 1))
}
#------------------

#------ xk and wk ------
laguerre <- glaguerre.quadrature.rules(n=100, alpha=0, normalized=FALSE)[[100]]
x <- laguerre[, 1]
w <- laguerre[, 2]
#-----------------------

#------ approx ------
approx <- function(theta, x, w)
{
  sum(w * exp(x) * f(x=x, theta=theta))
}
#--------------------

> approx(theta=0.5806, x=x, w=w)
[1] 0.1937522
> approx(theta=15, x=x, w=w)
[1] 0.01662866
```

Comment: Sorry, your integral is not showing up in the post.

Comment: @RonGordon: Should be fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry again, I still cannot see it.

Comment: @RonGordon: Sorry for the trouble! Hope it is ok now

Comment: You should recall that Gauss-Laguerre quadrature works best if the "infinite extent" portion of your integral behaves very much like $\exp(-x)$. This for instance is the reason why Gauss-Laguerre is not very useful for computing integrals like $\int_0^\infty \frac{\mathrm dx}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: @J.M.: Can you please be a little bit more explicit about "if the 'infinite extent' portion of your integral behaves very much like exp(−x)"

Comment: Well, you need to recall why we do Gaussian quadrature in the first place. This is because the function we are integrating can be decomposed into a "nice" part and a "nasty" part. The "nice" part is the factor of your integral that is well-approximated by a polynomial, while the nasty part is where all the singular/improper behavior comes from.

Comment: For Gauss-Laguerre, the nasty part is the integral  extending into infinity, which happens to have exponential decay. Confining that bad behavior to the nodes/weights is how one manages to get good results out of Gauss-Laguerre. It stands to reason, then, that if the "nasty" part looks nothing like an exponential (e.g. slower decay rate), then Gauss-Laguerre is not very useful.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks! Would would suggest something else to approximate my integral?

Comment: If you have an exact answer already with that nice a form, then there really isn't much point in finding an approximation, no?

Comment: @J.M. Actually, I am trying to approximate an integral with a similar form but which has no explicit solution. This one is an example to figure out the accuracy of my approximation.

Comment: In that case, maybe you should post your real problem, then.